# How to dynamically add server controls into repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have to display table with dynamically filled in data, structure and layout is a bit complicated so I use repeater which is rendered by custom logic into data.

Everything works smoothly for data to be displayed for regular users, but for administrators of the web site I need to allow some actions... but I don't see any easy and convenient way to do that.

What comes to my mind is to write something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="TeamsRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="t_data"><thead>
            ... some header controls here ...
        </thead><tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><%#((MyObject)Container.DataItem).MyValue%></td>
            <td runat="server"><asp:TextBox Value=<%#((MyObject)Container.DataItem).MyValue%></td>
            <td runat="server"><asp:button Text="Update"/></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
        </tbody></table>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Plus I need to add logic which will update visibility of all 3:

1. cell which displays uneditable MyValue (should be visible to regular users)
2. cell which displays editable MyValue (should be visible for admins)
3. cell which contains update button (should be visible for admins so they can trigger update action).

I feel if I proceed this way the code will be ugly and I don't really even see any way how can I implement that...

**Question:**

How should I change visibility of server controls?

Any advise is more than welcome!

Thank you.

P.S. My web site is written using ASP.NET 4.0 (though I can consider upgrading it to ASP.NET 4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it’s not a so simple task. In your case you need to fully customize repeater, you need to access controls and change properties of them, you need to have buttons and assign Event Handler to them.

So my answer maybe be a little long but I think it’s all of you need to fully customize an `ASP.NET Repeater`.

Please follow this answer step by step.

## The Assumptions

1. We have a Table with two Columns: ID and Title that is Bound to Repeater.

   [image]
2. We have an ASPX page like this:

   ```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Repeater ID="rptMyRepeater" ClientIDMode="AutoID" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMyRepeater_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptMyRepeater_ItemCommand" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:Button ID="btnSowID" CommandName="ShowID" runat="server" Text="Show ID" />
               <asp:Button ID="btnShowTitle" CommandName="ShowTitle" runat="server" Text="Show Title" />
               <br /><br />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
       <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
   </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:postdataConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Titles]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
   ```

   Inside the Repeater we have 3 Controls: two Buttons and one TextBox and outside the Repeater there is Label (lblMsg).

## The Scenario:

1. We want to show Titles in TextBoxes.
2. Display Buttons for odd IDs and hide them for even IDs.
3. By clicking on each Button, show the related row’s ID or Title In lblMsg.

   I think this senario cover all of other senarios and you can modify code to do any action else.

## Walkthrough:

1.In order to reach the first goal we use the `ItemDataBound` Event Handler:

```
protected void rptMyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.DataRowView dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        TextBox txtMyTextBox = e.Item.FindControl("txtMyTextBox") as TextBox;
        txtMyTextBox.Text = dataItem.Row["Title"].ToString();
    }
}
```

In the above we find the TextBox in Repeater and assign Title Column from Database.

**The Output:**

[image]

2.Now we want to display buttons for odd IDs and hide them for even IDs so add this section too:

```
Button btnSowID = e.Item.FindControl("btnSowID") as Button;
Button btnShowTitle = e.Item.FindControl("btnShowTitle") as Button;
if (Convert.ToInt32(dataItem.Row["ID"]) % 2 == 0)
{
    btnSowID.Visible = false;
    btnShowTitle.Visible = false;
}
```

In the above we find btnSowID and btnShowTitle in Repeater and check if ID of this row is even so set visiblity of related buttons as false.
It's obvious that you can implement any other condition. Show buttons if current user is an Admin for instance.

**The Output:**

[image]

3.Now we want to add Click Handler for each Button in Repater. As you can see in ASPX code we set `CommandName` Property for buttons, we use this property in future.

The final goal is on clicking each Button the `lblMsg` show us the ID or Title of same row that related Button clicked. So we need to recognize the row of clicked Button.

In order to reach that we assign the related ID or Title value to `CommandArgument` Property of each Button under the `ItemDataBound` handler.

So the final `ItemDataBound` must be like this:

```
    protected void rptMyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            TextBox txtMyTextBox = e.Item.FindControl("txtMyTextBox") as TextBox;
            txtMyTextBox.Text = dataItem.Row["Title"].ToString();

            Button btnSowID = e.Item.FindControl("btnSowID") as Button;
            btnSowID.CommandArgument = dataItem.Row["ID"].ToString();

            Button btnShowTitle = e.Item.FindControl("btnShowTitle") as Button;
            btnShowTitle.CommandArgument = dataItem.Row["Title"].ToString();

            if (Convert.ToInt32(dataItem.Row["ID"]) % 2 == 0)
            {
                btnSowID.Visible = false;
                btnShowTitle.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In order to catch the Click Events of Buttons that there are inside Repeater we use `ItemCommand` Handler. this handler help us to catch and process events of Controls inside the Repeater.
So we define the `ItemCommand` Handler like this:

```
    protected void rptMyRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "ShowID":
                lblMsg.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                break;

            case "ShowTitle":
                lblMsg.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
```

In the above we check the `CommandName` Property that set manually in ASPX code and determine that is ShowID Button or ShowTitle Button clicked.
When we find that in first step, then try to find that the Button is placed in which row. So we read the `CommandArgument` Property that set dynamically under the `ItemDataBound` Handler.

Also you can use this method to create buttons like btnEdit and btnRemove, set `CommandName`s as Edit and Remove and set `CommandArgument` as Row ID and doing Update or Delete in your database under `ItemCommand` Handler.

**The Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. For my knowledge that was not really required as I knew this approach and was looking for an alternative. But I strongly believe that will benefit other people.

Comment: @Budda: I felt that maybe you're looking for an inline code solution in aspx page (i thinks it's not mentioned in question clearly) but i think that in the future you will be faced with problems by inline solution in handling events and probably in scenario's changes also your code look likes messy and in two cases in think you have to use `ItemCommand` handler. so i think that CodeBehind solution is more neat and more flexible. Sorry if this answer wasn't exactly what you want.

Comment: Yup, I was looking for some type of inline solution. But looks like even if possible that would be really unreadable and non-maintainable. So thank you for an idea. Already implemented that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do it. However, I would encapsulate all the visibility logic in your objects and avoid if else logic in the binding expressions.

Answer (score 1):

We can create controls dynamically using PlaceHolder control inside repeater on ItemdataBound.

I am sharing following link which has full example.
[Dynamic control inside Repeater using placeholder in Asp.Net(c#)?][1]
http://programmerskills.blogspot.com/2016/05/dynamic-control-create-dynamic-control.html